# Vue 3 Composition API Provide/Inject not working in Single File Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm making a library in VueJS 3 using Composition API. I implemented Provide/Inject as mentioned in [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#injection-reactivity). But the property in child component is still undefined and I get following error in browser console:

[image: Console Output]

A very simple implementation of my code is as follow:

> Usage In Project

```
<ThemeProvider>
    <Button color="green">
        ABC
    </Button>
</ThemeProvider>

<script>
    import { ThemeProvider, Button } from 'my-library'

    export default {
        name: 'SomePage',
        setup() {...},
    }
</script>
```

> ThemeProvider.js (Parent Componen)

```
import { toRefs, reactive, provide, h } from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'theme-provider',
    props:
        theme: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => ({...}),
        },
    },
    setup(props, { slots }) {
        const { theme } = toRefs(props)

        provide('theme', reactive(theme.value))

        return () =>
            h(
                'div',
                {...},
                slots.default()
            )
    },
}
```

> Button.js (Child Component)

```
import { inject, h } from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'Button',
    setup(props, { slots }) {
        const theme = inject('theme')
        console.log(theme)  // returns undefined

        return () =>
            h(
                'button',
                {...},
                slots.default()
            )
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, the code had no problem. The problem was the difference in version for `'vue'` and `'@vue/compiler-sfc'` (Vue compiler for Single File Component) in my `package.json` file.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same warning and issue when using `async setup()`

> inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.

The problem was having an async call before the inject was initialised, I am not sure why it matters.

The solution was declaring the inject before the async function is being called.

```js
import getCharacters from "../composables/characters";
import { inject } from "vue";
export default {
  async setup() {
    const store = inject("store");
    const { characters } = await getCharacters();
    
    store.updateChars(characters)

    return {
      characters,
      store
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: To extend that a little bit: You can declare the variable as an initialized ref before running the async function inside of setup() and then assign ref.value = result after the awaited  call returns.
i.e.
 `const myRef = ref(""); let result = await asyncMethod(); myRef.value = result;`

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Worked for me in `script setup` syntax too.

Answer (score 0):

```html
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
```

I had the same warning shown while using vue-router inside the pinia store,just had to bring initialization of pinia  and router upfront of and try to rearrange it.

I was trying to call pinia store actions inside router main.js file even before router was initialized.

I was calling a toast action added in another store  to this store
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ6CI.png)

earlier it was like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTFex.png)

changed to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N12yE.png)