# Inject .js file into VueJS 3 component using provide

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inject

Im having a simple import problem in my VueJS 3 app. I have looked at this answer: [Vue 3 Composition API Provide/Inject not working in Single File Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107387/vue-3-composition-api-provide-inject-not-working-in-single-file-components) but did not find an answer.

I am importing my external file in main.js: `import * as myService from "./services/myService.js";`

Then also in main.js: `app.provide("myService", myService);`

And then in my component I have:

```
<script>

export default {
    name: "MyComponent",
    props: {
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        myFunc: function(){
            var result = myService.serviceFunction();
        }
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            ...
        }
    },
    inject: ["myService"]
}

</script>
```

But where I have `var result = myService.serviceFunction();` gives me the error that `myService` is undefined.

If I call `var result = myService.serviceFunction();` in main.js there is no error and the function is called correctly, so the problem must be with the VueJS injection.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `this` to get access to the injected item :

```
  methods: {
        myFunc: function(){
            var result = this.myService.serviceFunction();
        }
    },
```

Comment: I get the error that `this.myService is null` when I use `this`.